# Out of date files must be resolved or reverted | Perforce

Tags: perforce

I am a Perforce beginner (and a coder beginner to be frank). I got this error message when I Checkout → Submit. I would like to try to solve these out of date files, but what and where are they? Any advice would be great, thanks!

[Log does not seem to show any list of "out of date files"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWVWb.png)

Answer (score 1):

Look at changelist 51 in the "Pending" tab.  If there are any files with question marks next to them, they require a resolve (that's where you combine the changes in your workspace with newer changes from the depot).  You can resolve all outstanding files by just right-clicking changelist 51 and selecting "Resolve..."; it will iterate through all the necessary resolves automatically.

If that doesn't fix it, you should be able to get a better error message by going to the command line and running the `p4 submit -c 51` command suggested by the error message.  The submit will fail for the same reason, but at the command line you should be able to see the list of files that were included in the changelist, which ones failed to submit, and more information about why.  (For example, if a file has been deleted and you were trying to edit it, an edit makes no sense and you need to revert it and/or reopen it as a re-added file -- the error messages at the command line will give you more information about cases like these.)

Comment: Ah I see, thats what -c 51 means. 
I just reverted, continued playing around in unreal, Add and Submit then it works fine again. Not sure why but its working now. Thanks for the advice anyhow! Will refer to this in the future when I encounter the same issue. Cheers!

Comment: Reverting got you up to date with the latest changes in the depot by discarding all the open changes in your workspace -- the point of doing a resolve is to be able to merge the latest depot changes with your open changes without having to revert them and lose everything you've been working on, but if nothing in your workspace is valuable then reverting is generally the easier fix!